# In-app billing is not working on G1

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I've imlemented in-app billing in my Android application. It works fine on my own device with Android version 2.2 and Market version 2.3.4. But it is not working on testing device T-Mobile G1 with Android 1.6 and Market version 1002211 (strange version..but it has in-app billing permission). An exception is thrown:

```
ERROR/Bundle(2079): readBundle: bad magic number
ERROR/Bundle(2079): readBundle: trace = java.lang.RuntimeException
        at android.os.Bundle.readFromParcelInner(Bundle.java:1473)
        at android.os.Bundle.<init>(Bundle.java:82)
        at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1344)
        at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1329)
        at android.os.Bundle$1.createFromParcel(Bundle.java:1410)
        at android.os.Bundle$1.createFromParcel(Bundle.java:1413)
        at com.android.vending.billing.IMarketBillingService$Stub$Proxy.sendBillingRequest(IMarketBillingService.java:102)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingService$RestoreTransactions.run(BillingService.java:310)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingService$BillingRequest.runIfConnected(BillingService.java:118)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingService$BillingRequest.runRequest(BillingService.java:97)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingService.restoreTransactions(BillingService.java:428)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingActivity.restoreDatabase(BillingActivity.java:193)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingActivity.access$000(BillingActivity.java:45)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingActivity$PurchaseObserver.onBillingSupported(BillingActivity.java:107)
        at MyAppPackages.ResponseHandler.checkBillingSupportedResponse(ResponseHandler.java:83)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingService$CheckBillingSupported.run(BillingService.java:188)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingService$BillingRequest.runIfConnected(BillingService.java:118)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingService.runPendingRequests(BillingService.java:521)
        at MyAppPackages.BillingService.onServiceConnected(BillingService.java:554)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(ActivityThread.java:1053)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(ActivityThread.java:1070)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue on my LG P500 with an outdated market...
The problem is the run() method of the CheckBillingSupported sub class of the Billing-Service.

It will return "true" although the market does not support Billing ...

The response code will yield 0 since the extra field BILLING_RESPONSE_RESPONSE_CODE is not actually set - but instead defaults back to 0; Incidentally RESULT_OK is also 0.

```
int responseCode = response.getInt(Consts.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESPONSE_CODE);
```

To fix this replace the call with:

```
int responseCode = response.getInt(Consts.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESPONSE_CODE, -123);
```

This fixed my issue.